# Cocos2d-iPhone: Apply an image to a CCLabelTTF?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d-iPhone, I was wondering if it was possible to either apply an image to a text label, or use a text label as a mask for an image?

I was hoping to 'fill' a custom true type font with a pixel-art style dithered gradient. I assume using an image would be the best approach.

Is this at all possible with Cocos2d?

Cheers,

Adrian

Comment: that might be the kind of thing for which I would consider a shader. Pass the texture of the label (as a second texture) via the vertex shader of a CCSprite, and alpha-multiply the coloured texture in the fragment shader. YMMV, have not tried this but i intuite it could work for your need.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll have to broaden my knowledge of textures and shaders as I'm new to Cocos2d, and when I do I'll let you know how it worked out.